# How to find who created user and with which command or which program?

Tags: command-line, user-management

I see a new user is made. How to know who created and how (from which program)?

Answer (score 0):

When you have created a new user look in /var/log/auth.log; the details are in there. I just created new user jim by running sudo adduser jim, for example, and this is at the end of auth.log (I have removed the date and host name from the start of the log):

Comment: Where is log example?